# Metaclassing to solve dynamic class choosing with prevalidation?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, inheritance, metaclass

I'm extending a Python ORM with an `InType` field, which is a validator.

In fact, I am creating a whole number of validators... in web2py DAL terms I am emulating:

```
Field(type=String, validators=[IS_EMAIL(), IS_IN(['foo@bar.com'])])
```

However doing it all at the custom field level. I've tried to create a test-case here:

```
from types import StringType, IntType

class StringField(object):
    def validate(self, value):
        assert type(value) is StringType
        self.value = value


class IntField(object):
    def validate(self, value):
        assert type(value) is IntType
        self.value = value

class InField(object):
    """
        Confirms `value in enumerable` before putting
        in `StringField` or `IntField`
    """

    def validate(self, value, enumerable):
        assert value not in enumerable
        obj = (StringField if type(value) is StringType else IntField)()
        obj.validate(value)
        return obj
```

Rather than returning an instance object of a class figured out at runtime like above, I was thinking it'd be better to implement it using metaclassing, or some other technique.

#### How should I approach this problem?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish with InField but if you want to take a decision based on the type of a value at runtime, I can't see how a metaclass would help you.

Comment: Is there any approach better than mine? - IMHO this solution sucks

Comment: Considering that you want decide upon runtime which validator to pick, I can't think of a much better alternative solution. You could consider multimethods specialized by field type. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multimethods

Comment: Mmm, well I don't think multimethods are the right solution here, because that would require double-typing. The initial validation is consistent irrespective of types, then it needs to call the right type. Another solution would be to use a function rather than a class, with signature `(FieldClass, value, enumerable)`.